# Rails query with select, group and having won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@violators = User.includes(:violation).select('users.id, violations.id')
  .group('users.id, violations.id').having("COUNT(violations.user_id) >= ?", 5)
  .order("COUNT(violations.user_id) desc")
```

Each User `has_many` violations. With the query above, I am able to order the users who have the most violations, but I only want to see users who have 5 or more violations. When I insert 5, nothing shows up despite there being users with more than 5 violations. When I enter 1 in there, all the users with violations show up!

UPDATE:

I am not able to order users who have the most violations as I previously suggested. Maybe there is an issue with the actual count of violations. Its somehow not capturing them. Although when I check the console and try running - user.violation.count, it gives me the accurate count.

Comment: try with this in the having: `COUNT(violations.id) >= ?`

Comment: No, that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include `joins` in your request:

```
@violators = User.joins(:violations).includes(:violations)      
  .group('user_id').having('COUNT(*) >= ?', 5)
  .order('COUNT(*) desc')
```

---

I've tested it on my models `Championship` and `Match` (championship `has_many` matches) :

```
Championship.joins(:matches).includes(:matches)
  .group('championship_id').having('count(*) >= ?', 5).order('count(*) DESC').all
```

SQL request:

```
 SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT "championships"."id" AS t0_r0, "championships"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "championships"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "matches"."id" AS t1_r0, "matches"."championship_id" AS t1_r1, "matches"."created_at" AS t1_r9, "matches"."updated_at" AS t1_r10, "matches"."result" AS t1_r11, "matches"."map_token" AS t1_r12 FROM "championships" INNER JOIN "matches" ON "matches"."championship_id" = "championships"."id" GROUP BY championship_id HAVING count(*) >= 5 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: No, get the same result as below.

Comment: @pratski I've tested it with one of my `one_to_many` relation and it looks fine. Can you show the SQL generated by this request on your models ?

Comment: `[1mSELECT DISTINCT "users".id, COUNT(*) AS alias_0 FROM "users" INNER JOIN "violations" ON "violations"."user_id" = "users"."id" GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5 ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0[0m
PGError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "users".id, COUNT(*) AS alias_0 FROM "users...`

Comment: @pratski strange, my SQL request differs on `DISTINCT "users".id, COUNT(*) AS alias_0 `. I've updated my answer with my model and the SQL generated (more readable than in comments); Hope it will help.

Comment: This works! `@violators = User.joins(:violation).group('users.id').having("COUNT(violations.user_id) >= ?", 5).order("COUNT(violations.user_id) desc")`