# Count distinct records while plucking from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Given Rails app where:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :captain, class_name: User
```

I'm trying to succinctly query database and get a summary of Captains and the number of Teams they belong to:

```
[[23, "Pat", "Smith"]]  Teams: 1
[[46, "Kate", "Jones"]]  Teams: 1
[[107, "John", "Doe"]]  Teams: 3
...
```

I can get a hash with each Captain's ID and the number of teams:

```
> Team.group(:captain_id).count
=> {85=>3, 106=>1, 81=>1, 25=>1, 32=>1, 8=>3, 1=>1, 79=>2, 26=>1}
```

But then it gets ugly. The following works but seems ugly and has n+1 SQL queries:

```
Team.group(:captain_id).count.sort.to_h.each { |key,val| puts "#{User.where(id: key).pluck(:id, :first, :last)}  Teams: #{val}" }
```

What's the Rails way?

Comment: Your question isn't a direct duplicate, but you may find something useful in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252669/rails-query-with-select-group-and-having-wont-work). Also, make your association bidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to get detailed info about users, you may want to define a relation like this on your User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :captained_teams, foreign_key: :captain_id, class_name: Team
```

Then you can work with User for your query:

```
User.joins(:captained_teams).includes(:captained_teams).each do |user|
  puts "#{[user.id, user.first, user.last]}  Teams: #{user.captained_teams.length}"
end
```

Comment: I don't think you ever need both `.joins` and `.includes`. I think just `.includes` will do the job.

Comment: `.joins` is necessary to only consider users who are team captains.

Comment: Thats the rails way! controlling the queries on tables through `ActiveRecord`, keeping the queries as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

*`sql = "**Select count then group by then having count(...)**"`*

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql);

You can use the raw sql to get what you want.